# Update document is free or is it considered write operation?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

firestore is charging for reading, write and delete operation but update case is not mentioned 
firestore update document is free or is it considered write operation?
in pricing page, no details were given about update document case

Answer (score 0):

A write is billed any time a document is created or changed, including use of the update method.